# How to validate a variable

Tags: bash, loops

I have created the following script

```
for i in $(ls /home/test);
do health=$(curl -s http://192.168.1.100/api/stream_health/$i);
if [ $health = "true" ]
then echo "At `date` $i stream is running"
else
ps aux | grep -v grep | grep $(cat /root/bin/xproxy.conf | grep "$i" | cut -f3 -d":" | cut -c1-5) | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
fi
done;
```

The problem is that when $i if not found in /root/bin/xproxy.conf the script exits with grep error command. How would I put some kind of validation that if $i is not found in /root/bin/xproxy.conf then skip this loop and go to the next one.

Comment: [Don't parse the output from `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: `grep` not finding the value of `$i` in the file should not be killing that loop. It will cause an `xargs` error for lack of input but the loop should continue just fine unless you have `set -e` or similar turned on.

Comment: How does a sample line in `/root/bin/xproxy.conf` look like? there seems to be lot of scope for optimization. e.g. `cat | grep`, `ps | grep -v grep | grep`, `grep | cut` etc can be possibly optimized.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
[[ $(grep $i /root/bin/xproxy.conf ]] || continue
```

Answer (score 0):

1) grep can find expresions in a file with: `grep expresion file`. So you do not need to use: `cat file | grep expresion`

2.a) You can use && operator, it can be interpreted as "*If* previous command is success (really exit code = 0) *then* excutes next command

```
grep $i /root/bin/xproxy.conf && ps aux | grep -v grep | grep $(grep "$i" /root/bin/xproxy.conf  | cut -f3 -d":" | cut -c1-5) | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

2.b) Other way is asking for exit code after excution of grep with special variable ?:

```
grep $i /root/bin/xproxy.conf &>/dev/null
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
    ps aux | grep -v grep | grep $(grep "$i" /root/bin/xproxy.conf  | cut -f3 -d":" | cut -c1-5) | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
fi
```